Nested Scroll View auto scroll to top when set notifyItemChanged in recycle view
I use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView, my RecyclerView set layoutManager = GridLayoutManager.
My problem happen when i set notifyItemChange in recycleView, view in nestedscrollView auto scroll to top, it not keep position
This is mycode
XML
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/vtb_sdk_15sdp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/vtb_sdk_90sdp">


            //other code

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_qr_background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/vtb_sdk_15sdp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_background" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

Code block set recycle view
 val linearLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        mBinding.rvQrBackground.apply {
            adapter = qrBackgroundAdapter
            layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        }

Code block set in adapter
root.setThrottleClickListener {
                    if (selectedItem != position) {
                        val oldPosition = selectedItem
                        selectedItem = position
                        notifyItemChanged(oldPosition)
                        notifyItemChanged(position)
                    }
                    onItemClickListener?.invoke(this, position)
                }

I added
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

into ConstraintLayout, but it not work.

The problem occurs with some views above the RecyclerView. Show all the code.
